# Is the correlation coefficient just the standard deviations of x and y multiplied together?

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, standard-deviation, descriptive-statistics

Is $r = \frac{\sum{(x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}}{\sqrt{\sum(x_i-\bar{x})^2}\sqrt{\sum(y_i-\bar{y})^2}} $ the same as $\sum{\frac{(x_i-\bar{x})}{\sigma_x}\frac{(y_i-\bar{y})}{\sigma_y}}$ which is just multiplication of the standard deviation of $x_i$ multiplied by the standard deviation $y_i$ for every $i$ summed up?

Comment: No, the correlation coefficient is not a function of the standard deviations of $x$ and $y$ at all. If it were it wouldn't be measuring correlation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not.
The mistake in the equations you posted is that the product of the standard deviations is not

$$\sum_i{\frac{(x_i-\bar{x})}{\sigma_x}\frac{(y_i-\bar{y})}{\sigma_y}}$$

but rather

$$\left(\sum_i \frac{x_i-\bar{x}}{\sigma_x}\right) \left(\sum_i \frac{y_i-\bar{y}}{\sigma_y}\right)$$

In the correlation coefficient you sum only once, thus "connecting" the two quantities $x$ and $y$, whereas the standard deviation is something you can calculate for each quantity on its own.

Comment: Thank you for your response, would a more accurate interpretation be proportion of the standard deviation of x for a single $x_i$, multiplied by the proportion of a single standard deviation of $y_i$ summed up across $i$ @tehforsch

Comment: @user372382 i'm afraid i am not sure what you mean by "proportion of a single standard deviation of ...".
(by the way, i always liked this picture https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d4/Correlation_examples2.svg which i think illustrates the correlation coefficient quite nicely)

Comment: This is a very interesting picture data comes in so many shapes I was trying to interpret it as for each individual $x_i$ and $y_i$ we are measuring its individual number of standard deviations from $\bar{x}$ or from $\bar{y}$ and then multiplying them together and summing them up for each $i$ I appreciate your response thank you for all of your help @tehforsch